# how to validate a captcha on my registration page

Tags: php

i am trying to put a simple captcha on registration page but i am getting failing to validate the captcha part on my form
if i leave the username part on the form blank and press register it will give me a message please enter username and so on but when it comes to the captcha part if i leave it blank it will give a message enter captcha but if i enter the captcha letter but not the correct one it registers,so i want to try and combine this code below

```
if ( $real == $guess ) {
    die ("enter captcha");
}
```

and this code

```
if ( $real != $guess ) {
   die ("Not equal");
}
```

this is my register page code

```
//Collecting info
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$pass_conf = $_REQUEST['password_conf'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$guess = $_POST['captcha'];

$real = ( isset( $_SESSION['real'] ) ) ? $_SESSION['real'] : "";

//Here we will check do we have all inputs filled

if ( empty( $username ) ) {
    die("Please enter your username!<br>");
}

if ( empty( $password ) ) {
    die("Please enter your password!<br>");
}

if ( empty( $pass_conf ) ) {
   die("Please confirm your password!<br>");
}

if ( empty( $email ) ) {
   die("Please enter your email!");
}
if ( $real == $guess ) {
   die ("enter captcha");
} 

//Let's check if this username is already in use

$user_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$do_user_check = mysql_num_rows( $user_check );

//Now if email is already in use

$email_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$do_email_check = mysql_num_rows( $email_check );

//Now display errors

if ( $do_user_check > 0 ) {
    die("Username is already in use!<br>");
}

if ( $do_email_check > 0 ) {
    die("Email is already in use!");
}

//Now let's check does passwords match

if( $password != $pass_conf ) {
   die("Passwords don't match!");
}

//If everything is okay let's register this user

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");
if ( !$insert ) {
   die("There's little problem: ".mysql_error());
}

echo $username.", you are now registered. Thank you!<br><a href=login.php>Login</a> | <a href=index.php>Index</a>";

}
$act = isset($_GET['act']) ? $_GET['act'] : '';
switch( $act ) {
   default;
   register_form();
   break;

   case "register";
   register();
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
if (empty($guess) || $guess !== $real)
{
    die("Please enter the correct CAPTCHA.<br>");
}

// the CAPTCHA entered was correct
...
```

Comment: bot working itd doing the same thing when i enter correct data its still giving me please enter the correct captcha

Comment: Try printing out `$guess` and `$real`, see if they are what you expect.

Comment: how? i don't understand what you saying

Comment: `var_dump($guess)` and `var_dump($real)`. Look at them and make sure they are the same (or at least what you *think* they should be).

Comment: getting the undefines variable for $real and $guess

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
    if ( $real == $guess ) {
   die ("enter captcha");
}
```

says "enter captcha" only if real is equal to the guess. Thus it is the opposite of what you really want and thus the cause of the problem.

You would need to change it to:

```
    if ( $real != $guess ) {
   die ("enter captcha");
}
```

Which would print the "enter captcha" phrase if real is **not** equal to the guess.

Comment: its what i have been doing but its still giving erros

Comment: btw as I did not see it in your example code: Did you use session_start()   as $real is set with the help of a session variable?